# Python how to update and write attributes in another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a parser module for a specific type of python file. (Target file is a config file, where I want to read and update values and finally write to it).

This is how the target python file looks like : (config.py)

```
class MailConfig(object):
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    MAIL_USE_TLS = False
    MAIL_USE_SSL = True
    MAIL_DEBUG = False

    # administrator list
    ADMINS = [('abc', 'abc@gmail.com'),
              ('xyz', 'xyz@gmail.com')]
```

I've tried and got it partially working using fileinput module (or it'd work using any other basic file writing) but it fails when an attribute spans over multiple lines, obviously.

I'd like to create a python module which can update the specified attribute's value in config.py file. For e.g. I want to remove ADMINS value to [('abc', 'abc@gmail.com), ]

I tried using importlib module, but can't get it working to write to the file as well. Basically I want similar to json's load and dump for py file.

And I can't control the config.py file, it's a standard that I have to live with. Means it can't be a json file.

Comment: There are actually a bunch of ways to do that, but why are you doing this? I sus that what you do is inefficient. What is the use case?

Comment: take a look at jinga2 template library

Comment: Yeah or rather Mako https://www.makotemplates.org/

Comment: Why not just use a .json config file rather than hard-coding the values in a .py file at all?

Comment: I can't control the config.py file, it's a standard that I have to live with.